# ExpiredKeyMapError - still error even if I generate a new API

Tags: javascript, wordpress, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a wordpress website made in 2016, and now the map doesn't work properly 
 anymore because of this console error (ExpiredKeyMapError).

I have created a new API but still doesn't work.

I have tried deleting the cache but still...

Maybe i need to wait some days for the new API starts to work properly? Or there is a way to make it work?

Anyone can help me?

Comment: How could we know? How did you generate the new key? Did you apply any restrictions? Do you have a valid billing account associated with it? etc. etc. [Read the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages) and if you believe you have done everything properly, then you should contact Google support as your question is off-topic for this website.

Comment: `I have created a new API but still doesn't work.` Did you replace the old key with the new one?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, because the template had a problem with API, i needed to contact the helpdesk.
Thank to all.